# Problema con instalación Guest Additions en Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Tengo este problema al tratar de instalar las guest additions, no me queda muy claro si ya se instalaron o sigue habiendo problema

```
darioxlz@darioxlz-VirtualBox:/media/darioxlz/VBox_GAs_5.2.16$ sudo 
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run 
[sudo] contraseña para darioxlz: 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.2.16 Guest Additions for Linux........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.2.16 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel 
modules.  This may take a while.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced 
until the system is restarted
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
```

Comment: `until the system is restarted`  faltaría reiniciar parece

Comment: Eso creo, pero la función de arrastrar y soltar no sirve

Comment: eso requiere un shared folder mepa, fijate si está configurada

Comment: Si la tengo configurada

Comment: Si quieres saber si están arriba, ejecuta un lsmod |grep vbox . Así sabrás si están cargados los módulos. También puedes ejecutar grep vboxsf /var/log/boot o en /var/log/messages y te saldrá si se han cargado bien o porqué no cargan.